# How to use DSL query from Kibana dev-tools in visualisation?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, visualization, elasticsearch-dsl

I have successfully aggregated and queried a particular content I needed in Kibana Dev Tools. However, I need this information in a tabular form either as CSV or PDF. For this, I need to run the DSL query I constructed in Dev Tools in visualisation tool of Kibana. However, I am not able to do it.

I tried copying the DSL to the Lucene query text box on the top part of the visualisation page and also tried within the add filter option. Both way it returns an error.

The query that works in Dev Tools:

```
{

  "query": {
    "bool": {
       "must": [
        { "match": { "start_datetime":"1569868200" }}
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs" : {
        "state_location" : {
            "terms": {
                "field" : "state_location"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "stakeholder_category": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "stakeholder_category"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "coverage_category": {
                            "terms": {
                            "field": "category_paragraph_name.keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expecting to get the result on visualisation screen as a table, so that I can export it to CSV or PDF.

Answer (score 0):

The search bar in the discovery bar doesn't work with the json-syntax of a search request towards the REST-API. Instead it uses a simple lucene syntax.

However, you still can edit your search in the discovery manually:
You should be able to see a button with the label "Inspect" like in the following figure.

[image]

Note that the look & feel of Kibana got a significant update, so depending of the version you are using, you will find the Inspect button somewhere else in the discovery)

By hitting the button, a right-sided pane will show up with three tabs (Statistics, Request and Response). In the Request-section you can paste your query. Be sure NOT to past the root "query"-node of your json.

[image]

Hope, this will help you :-)

Comment: The request tab there is a read-only field